# How to parse JSON api using JAVA?

Tags: java

I am new on JAVA, how to parse the countryname using this API: https://iplist.cc/api

Use JAVA to parse the JSON: https://iplist.cc/api

Get ONLY the "countryname" value.

For example,

If the country name is  **"countryname": "Germany",**

The OUTPUT should be only:
**Germany**

I tried this but did not work :(

```
    public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {}

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}


// url to make request
private static String url = "https://iplist.cc/api";

// JSON Node names
private static final String COUNTRY_NAME = "countryname";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;



// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {

    country = json.getString(COUNTRY_NAME);

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Please post the whole code.

Comment: ***but did not work*** what did not work? Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

For such deserialization purpose, I would recommend you to use Gson (or another of this kind).

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Prepare IP class for deserialization:

```
public class IP {
    public final String ip;
    public final String registry;
    public final String countrycode;
    public final String countryname;
    public final String detail;
    public final boolean spam;
    public final boolean tor;

    public IP(String ip, String registry,
              String countrycode, String countryname,
              String detail, boolean spam, boolean tor) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.registry = registry;
        this.countrycode = countrycode;
        this.countryname = countryname;
        this.detail = detail;
        this.spam = spam;
        this.tor = tor;
    }
}
```

Deserialize from JSON String with Gson:

```
IP ip = new Gson().fromJson(json, IP.class);
System.out.println(ip.countryname);
```

Answer (score 0):

First add [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library to your project. this is for converting String to JSONObject.

```
public class HttpGet {

  public static String readGetRequestData(String urlToRead) throws IOException {
//    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "ip");
//    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "port"); if you got some proxy set it
    URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    return new String(connection.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = readGetRequestData("https://iplist.cc/api");
    try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
      System.out.println(jsonObject.get("countryname"));
    } catch (JSONException err) {
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

result is: **Germany**

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am using Java 8. This isn't working: return new String(connection.getInputStream().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Comment: @ejade you just need to read inputstream as a string so search google, in Java 8 has different ways of reading InputStream as String. I did not check your BufferedReader. if it works you may change my code with yours